# Using Squeryl inside a OSGi container

Tags: scala, osgi, apache-karaf, karaf, squeryl

Has anyone successfully gotten Squeryl to work inside a OSGi environment, specifically on Karaf 3.03.

So far I have gotten the individual dependencies to load, scala libraries, squeryl and the jdbc driver.The installed bundles look something like this:

```
51 | Resolved |  80 | 0.3.0.SNAPSHOT                            | ac.za.cput.pe.model                           
52 | Active   |  80 | 2.11.6.v20150224-172222-092690e7bf        | Scala Standard Library                        
53 | Active   |  80 | 0                                         | wrap_mvn_org.squeryl_squeryl_2.10_0.9.5-6     
54 | Active   |  80 | 2.10.0.v20121205-112020-VFINAL-18481cef9b | Scala Standard Library                        
55 | Active   |  80 | 0                                         | wrap_mvn_cglib_cglib-nodep_2.2                
56 | Active   |  80 | 0                                         | wrap_mvn_org.scala-lang_scalap_2.10.0         
57 | Active   |  80 | 2.10.0.v20121205-112020-VFINAL-18481cef9b | Scala Compiler                                
58 | Active   |  80 | 2.10.0.v20121205-112020-VFINAL-18481cef9b | Scala Reflect                                 
59 | Active   |  80 | 0                                         | wrap_mvn_postgresql_postgresql_9.1-901-1.jdbc4
```

In my bundle I have code that looks like this:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")
SessionFactory.concreteFactory = Some(()=>
  Session.create(
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pe","postgres"
    ,"12345"),new PostgreSqlAdapter
  )
)
```

which basically tries to create squeryl session factory.

However when I start up karaf, this is the error I am getting:

> java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.squeryl.SessionFactory$.concreteFactory_$eq(Lscala/Option;)V" the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoaderJava5) of the current class, ac/za/cput/pe/model/activator/Activator, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/felix/framework/BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoaderJava5) for resolved class, org/squeryl/SessionFactory$, have different Class objects for the type concreteFactory_$eq used in the signature

Does anyone have any ideas?, I am a few hours from jumping out of my balcony :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like you got some different Jars included.
First make sure you have all dependencies correctly imported. Second make sure you don't embed those dependencies partially in your own bundles. 
The Error message is very clear about the issue.

You compiled with a different version then the one that is provided to you during runtime. This Might be because of either a wrong import (make sure the version matches) or you include a different version of the package in your bundle.